# How to achive dynamic binding with ArrayList<T> in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, dynamic-binding

It looks like ArrayList in Java do not support dynamic binding. When I tried to do following code it gave compile time error. 

 Code:

```
class Value
{
    <some variables>
    <some methods>
}

class IntegerValue extends Value
{
int value;
}

class CharacterValue extends Value
{
char value;   
}

class Main{

ArrayList<Value> values = null;
public static void main(String args[])
{
    swtich(args[1])
    {
        case "integer":
        values = new ArrayList<IntegerValue>();
        break;

        case "character":
        values = new ArrayList<CharacterValue>();
        break;

        default:
        values = new ArrayList<Value>();

    }
}
}
```

It looks like ArrayList does not support dynamic binding but Array does. When I did Value[] values = new IntegerValue[maxSize], it did compiled by creating references of superclass type. But what if I dont know size at the beginning and also want dynamic behaviour with data structure (something like what ArrayList can do) ? Is there any other way to achieve this ? Are there any other data structures for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic binding? And why are you trying to create your own Wrapper Classes?

Comment: Hint: Search for "covariance and generics", that should give you some pointers. In short, ``List<IntegerValue>`` is not ``List<Value>``; if you would "declare" a ``List<IntegerValue>`` through ``List<Value>``, this would allow you to add arbitrary ``Value``s to the list.

Comment: Even if I have declared IntegerValue as subclass of Value ?

Comment: @Dhwanit: Nope.  `List<? extends Value>` would work, though.

Comment: This is great Louis ! :)